# Route not loading

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm having issues with a route in Zend Framework 2. For instance, in module.config.php I have it set up as follows:

```
 'user' => array(
     'type' => 'Segment',
     'options' => array(
        'route' => 'user[/:action][/:store_id]',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\User',
            'action'     => 'index',
         ),
     ),
 ),
```

Now, I have a function in JavaScript that calls the route part [/:store_id] when a image is clicked on.

```
 function viewStore(id) {
     if (typeof id !== undefined) {
         $.getJSON('/user/store/' + id, function(data) {
                     document.getElementById('view-store-modal').style.display = 'block';

         $.each(data, function(i) {
               $('#main-store-name').html(data[i].store_name);

               $("#main-store-image").prop('src', data[i].store_image);
               $("#main-store-image").addClass("w3-padding").addClass("w3-round");
               $('#main-store-image').attr('style', 'width: 400px; height: 200px; display: block');

               $('#main-store-description').html("Store Description: " + data[i].store_description);
               $('#main-store-category').html("Store Category: " + data[i].store_category);

              if (data[i].number_of_items === null) {
                  $('#main-store-items').html("No items exist for this store yet, go add some!");
              } else {
                 $('#main-store-items').html("Number Of Items: " + data[i].number_of_items);
               }
         });
      });
   }
 }
```

Here is the controller code:

```
 public function storeAction()
{
    $layout = $this->layout();
    $layout->setTerminal(true);

    $view_model = new ViewModel();
    $view_model->setTerminal(true);

    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('store_id');

    if ($id !== null) {
        try {
            echo json_encode($this->getUserService()->getStoreFromId((int)$id));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo json_encode(array('failure' => $e->getMessage()));
        }
    }

    return $view_model;
}
```

And this is the method that retrieves the rows:

```
  public function getStoreFromId(int $store_id) : array
  {
    if ($store_id != 0 || $store_id !== null) {
        $query = $this->sql->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->execute("SELECT COUNT(i.store_id) AS number_of_items,
        stores.store_name, stores.store_description, stores.store_category, stores.store_image FROM items AS i
        INNER JOIN stores ON stores.store_id = i.store_id WHERE stores.store_id = " . $store_id);

        if ($query->count() > 0) {
            $row = [];

            foreach ($query as $value) {
                $row[] = $value;
            }

            return $row;
        } else {
            $select = $this->select->columns(array('store_id', 'store_name', 'store_description', 'store_category', 'store_image'))
                ->from('stores')
                ->where(array('store_id' => $store_id));

            $query = $this->sql->getAdapter()->query(
                $this->sql->buildSqlString($select),
                Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
            );

            if ($query->count() > 0) {
                $row = [];

                foreach ($query as $value) {
                    $row[] = $value;
                }

                return $row;
            } else {
                throw new \Exception("Could not locate store.");
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("Invalid store id given.");
    }
}
```

When I call it, it is like this:

```
<img src="<?php  echo $this->basePath()  . $store['store_image']; ?>" alt="Your Store" style="width: 100%;" onclick="viewStore(<?php echo $store['store_id']; ?>);">
```

Now, that does show all the store ids but when I click on any id but the first image, I am getting this response (shown in screenshots)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yALUv.jpg

I'm not sure why any of the ids that are not 23 do not load. Right now, all are listed from the stores table but only the id 23 actually works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the query. I changed it to this:

```
    SELECT stores.store_id,
    (SELECT count(b.store_id) FROM items b WHERE b.store_id = " . $store_id . " and stores.store_id = b.store_id) AS number_of_items, stores.store_name, stores.store_description, stores.store_category, stores.store_image FROM stores
    WHERE stores.store_id = " .  $store_id
```

and it worked just fine.